# Can I set default access settings?

Tags: webforms, 9

The Webform module defaults to allowing anonymous and authenticated users to submit a form.

The vast majority of the webforms we use are for internal staff that have a particular Drupal role.

Is there a setting for defaulting to a particular role/roles when creating a new form? There seems to be for everything else.

We are using Drupal 9.5.x and Webform 6.1.x.

Comment: Based on https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2875833 it is likely someone here has to invent a way.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [webform.api.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/6.1.x/webform.api.php#L653) there is a specific hook for that:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_access_rules_alter().
 */
function mymodule_webform_access_rules_alter(array &$access_rules) {
  if (isset($access_rules['create'])) {
    $access_rules['create']['roles'] = ['editor', 'moderator'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - so the solution to this would be to write a module.  OK, one for the backlog...!